# PostgreSQL with pg8000 - INSERT results from an SQL to another table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, pg8000

I am trying to copy rows form a PostgreSQL table to another one, using pg8000 driver for Python. This is the code:

```
import pg8000
conn = pg8000.connect(user="postgres", password="XXXXX",database="test")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM exampletable")
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

What I want now is to completely insert the results to a new table. It should be something like:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO secondtable VALUES (%s)", results)
```

but is not functioning this way and I don't know how to fix it. Not all fields are of string type, maybe that's should be fixed somehow?

Comment: you can do that in one go using INSERT INTO secondtable SELECT * FROM exampletable

Comment: I want to copy one table from one database to another database, so I need 2 cursors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the format %s is for scalar values. Convert results into a string, like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO secondtable VALUES %s" % str(results))
```

Comment: It shows me an error: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pg8000\core.py", line 1566, in execute ps = cache['ps'][key] KeyError: ((705,), 'INSERT INTO secondtable VALUES %s')

Comment: yes, sorry, replace the comma with % (see revised answer)

Comment: Now it gives: TypeError: executemany() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param_sets'

Comment: Not all fields are of string type, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: no, just use execute instead of executemany. The problem with executemany is that you need to specify the number of columns in advance.

Comment: Now it gives: pg8000.ProgrammingError: (b'ERROR', b'42601', b'syntax error at or near "["'). It seems I should somehow remove the [, tried to convert the list to a tuple, but again error: pg8000.ProgrammingError: (b'ERROR', b'25P02', b'current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block'

Comment: I solved the last problem with conn.rollback(). So your answer is correct. Just instead of results, should be used tuple(results)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic, but the search for a related question leads here.  I wanted to know how to format the bound variables for the execute sql string.  The format given in koriander's answer does not work with pg8000 1.10.5.  Here's what ended up working for me:

```
    some_field_value = 'value'
    sql = 'SELECT a_field FROM your_table WHERE some_field = %s'
    cursor.execute(sql, [some_field_value])
```

Details from the docs: [pg8000 Cursor.execute](https://pythonhosted.org/pg8000/dbapi.html#pg8000.Cursor.execute)

The important bit:

> args – If paramstyle is qmark, numeric, or format, this argument should be an array of parameters to bind into the statement

Two things to keep in mind:

1. pg8000 never accepts quotes around the format string (%s)
2. The value of pg8000.paramstyle matters. default value is 'format'

Answer (score -1):

The way to do this is with the cursor's [executemany](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#pg8000dbapicursorexecutemanyoperation-param_sets) method.

Let's say we want to copy the contents of our `users` table to another table named `users_copy`<sup>*</sup>. We need to fetch the rows, then construct an `INSERT` statement to execute.

```py
import pg8000

conn = pg8000.connect(user='souser', password='password', database='test')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Fetch the data.
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
results = cursor.fetchall()

# Construct the INSERT statement, dynamically creating the correct
# number of placeholders for the VALUES clause.
placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(results[0]))
stmt = f"""INSERT INTO users_copy VALUES ({placeholders})"""

# Insert to results into the target table.
cursor.executemany(stmt, results)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

---

<sup>*</sup> The question specifies that the target table is in another database, but we don't need to connect to another database to demonstrate the technique.  If the target table were in the same database then `SELECT INTO`, `CREATE TABLE AS` or `INSERTINTO ... SELECT * FROM ...` could be used to avoid having to retrieve the data, as [koriander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2207101/koriander) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399053/postgresql-with-pg8000-insert-results-from-an-sql-to-another-table#comment45134780_28399053).